# GetDataInBackgroundWithBlock | imageData is returning a nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, null

So I am saving some objects to the localDatastore using parse.

```
//Pin the objects here!!
var imageObject = PFObject(className: "img")
imageObject["theFile"] = imageFile
imageObject.pinInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
        imageObject.saveEventually()
        println("object pinned in background")
   } else {
        println(error)
   }
})
```

Then in the viewDidLoad I am querying the objects and appending them into an array of PFFile's

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "img")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
   if error == nil{
        var objects : AnyObject = objects as! AnyObject
        for object in objects as! [AnyObject]{
            self.testImages.append(object["theFile"] as! PFFile)
        }
   } else {
       println(error)
   }
}
```

With this array now containing data. I am trying to insert the images into the tableView

```
if testImages.count >= 1{
     testImages[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
           //The app crashes here ~ fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
           cell.theImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
         } else {
            println(error)
         }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a tableview, I think the best way is to download all the images from Parse and save it to an array. Then in the **cellForRowAtPath** method then you assign each index of that array to the cell.imageView.image

```
 var query = PFQuery(className:"img")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil
    {
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
        {
            for one in objects 
           {
               var pictureImage = one["theFile"] as! PFFile
                pictureImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (dataToget:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil 
                    {
                   if let  Image = UIImage(data: dataToget)
                     {
                        // save the image to array 
                        // reload the tableview
                      }
                    }
               })

             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ~  var Image = UIImage(data: dataToGet!)

Comment: so try if let image = UIImage(data:dataToget) {}

Comment: you are welcome .. please vote the answer :) Thank you